# Time Puzzle Rebus

Tags: rebus

The rebus puzzle is shown in the picture below. 
[image]

Comment: You can accept the correct answer! Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer posted after another was accepted, but I think a good alternative could be

> The Beginning of Time.

Answer (score 14):

I think it's:

> **Time is up**: The period of time allowed for something is ended.

Because:

> The arrow is pointing up where time is. So time is up [there].

Answer (score 6):

It could be

> Tea time
>  (T + time)

Comment: Haha, looks like you beat me to the punch, nice one. +1

Answer (score 4):

It could be

> High time, as in "It's high time someone solved this puzzle".

Or it could be

> Uptime, as in the amount of time a server has been running.

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> Tea time

Since

> the arrow is pointing to the letter "t" opposed to the whole word it may be suggesting the word tea.

Answer (score 1):

It can be

> Time arrow. As scientist usually use, to explain the beginning and end of time.